# Best algorithm to split a binary file into two files in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to split a binary file into two files based on the record number in the most efficient way in java.

The user has to provide a record number and if the recordNo of a record read from the file is less than this number, add the record to first file, otherwise to the second file.

At present, I am using an `Inputstream` to read the records one by one from the input file and based on the recordNo decide whether it goes to the first file or the second file.

This feature can't be consider as a sorting algorithm, this is just checking if the condition is met to then move the record to the correct file.

I would just like to know if there is any better algorithm available for this in java, if yes then please provide me the algorithm to achieve it in a better way.

Comment: are the records sorted?

Comment: yeah, records are already sorted based on record number.

Comment: Split different ideas in separate paragraphs, expanded abbreviations, fixed up some grammar and internal consistency.

Comment: _If_ you can **reliably** identify record boundaries in the middle of a byte stream, you could find the point with lower numbered records before and higher numbered records after using binary search - if not, going buffered using no less than one of your OS's bigger page sizes (4MBytes?) is the best you can do.

Comment: Given Java's thin interface to the rest of the world, you got to be an extra strength believer to think that the [Java FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-) [transfer functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-long-long-) are helping any - so do a benchmark, and be sure to have it going for 5 seconds, _at the very least_.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RandomAccessFile` and binary-search for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the file using a normal `FileInputStream` and you are performing small `read` calls (like for a single byte or a few bytes), then you should wrap the `FileInputStream` in a new `BufferedInputStream` to reduce the number of calls into the operating system to read data. That will improve the performance quite a bit.

If you are already only reading the data in large chunks (more than 8000 byte chunks or so) then you don't need to change anything.

Otherwise your approach looks sound. Since you need to read the entire input file in any case, in order to split it out into two output files, there is no use for optimizations that just take a bit of data out of the input file.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for ur valuable comment. Yeah, i doing the same which you have mentioned in ur comment but just like to know if any more optimized algo available to do it.

Comment: @piks I think that's in my answer. Since you are copying the entire file, there is no faster way than reading the entire file. Perhaps memory-mapping it using a `FileChannel` may offer a slight improvement over `InputStream` but I doubt it's worth the effort. If, on the other hand, you were selectively copying records out of the file, then you would gain a lot of improvement by first seeking to the correct location, like others suggested.